# What does orthonomality mean?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-fields, cross-product

According to me two vectors are orthogonal when they perpendicular so that their inner product is zero. But what do we mean that two functions are orthogonal ?
Or how to derive this?
$$\langle f,g \rangle =\int_b^af(x)g(x) $$
The only way this possible is that, the solutions of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are   vectors,for simplicity 2D vectors and
$$\langle f,g \rangle = 0$$ only if **all the solution vectors are perpendicular** to each other.

Comment: We don't derive this, rather we define inner product between two functions in an inner product space and then speak on orthogonality based on the defined inner product.

Comment: I don't  have much experience in linear algebra, but how do you define this :( ?

Comment: Kudos for the "according to me" expression

Comment: By "solutions of $f(x)$" do you mean the set $\{x:f(x)=0\}$? If so, you are understanding it wrong.

Comment: Yes, @trisct By solutions I meant the vectors  $$[x,f(x)]$$

Comment: I see...It seems you have an incorrect idea of why $f$ is a vector. I'll explain in an answer.

Comment: All you need for orthogonality is some vector space  and an inner product: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space . You can be rather creative here. Try e.g. the trivial vector space $V=\{0\}$ over the trivial field $F=\{0\}$. You can now consider $0$ to be equivalent to the function $f:V\rightarrow V$ and define the inner product $<.,.>:V\times V\rightarrow F$, $<v_1,v_2>=0$. It's really up top you how you define your space. In this case, all your functions are orthogonal.

Comment: @Tim Crosby Besides for the title: Orthonormality is not the same as orthogonality , a system of vectors $\{v_j:j\in J\}\subset V$ in a vector space $V$ and for some idexing set $J$ is orthonormal if it is orthogonal, i.e. $\langle v_j,v_k\rangle =0$ for $j\neq k$ $\textbf{and }$$\langle v_j,v_j\rangle =1$ for each $j\in J$, which is in short $\langle v_j, v_k\rangle =\delta_{kl}$ , where $\delta_{kl}$ denotes the Kronecker symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are having a hard time understanding why $f$ is vector because you've only seen vectors in Euclidean spaces, so whenever you see the word vector, you'd try to associate it to a vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

But we need adopt a more general definition of vectors and vector spaces. In fact in linear algebra, a **vector space** is any set where you can add its elements, multiply its elements by a real number so that certain properties like commutativity of addition, distribution law, etc. are satisfied. Any element of a vector space is called a **vector**.

Here, the set you should think about is
$$V=\{f:f\text{ is a square integrable function on $D$}\}$$
where $D$ is the common domain for all functions in $V$. To check that this is a vector space, you need only ask yourself:

1. If $f,g\in V$, does $f+g\in V$?
2. If $f\in V,a\in\mathbb R$, does $af\in V$?
3. Do $f+g=g+f$ and $a(f+g)=af+ag$, etc. hold?

Apparently they do, so $V$ is a vector space, and any $f\in V$ is a vector. Based on this we then **define** the inner product of $f,g$ as the integral of their product.

For the exact axioms of a vector space you can refer to any textbook. For why we can define the inner product this way you can refer to YJT's answer.

**P.S.** As suggested by Peter Melech, many generalizations are possible. For example $f$ can map to $\mathbb C$, or $D$ can be any measurable space.

Comment: +1 I would recommend though to distinguish between the images $f(x)$ of an element $x$ in the domain and the function $f:D(f)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto f(x)$ where $D(f)$ could be taken to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, of course $f$ could also map to $\mathbb{C}$ and the inner product would be defined by $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\overline{g(x)}d\lambda_n$ with $\lambda_n$ a Lebesgue measure, and many more generalizations possible

Comment: Of course an inner product on a vectorspace is defined as a bilinear function satisfying $\langle v, v\rangle =0$ if and only if $v=0$ for a vector $v$ and one  has to show that the integral obeys these rules

Comment: @PeterMelech Thanks. Indeed it is ambiguous to write $f(x)$ to mean the function.

Comment: So we are assuming f and g to be a part of the vector space. But then f and g should be vectors. How do we define vector f ?  For example if $f(x) = x$,do the vectors  resemble [2,2] , [1,1], [3,3] . .....

Comment: @TimCrosby No, $f$ itself is single vector simply because it belongs to a set that satisfies the definition of a vector space. Please forget everything about Euclidean vectors you have learned. Don't try to picture $f$ as an Euclidean one and don't try to write it in a coordinate form (because there isn't one). Then simply read the above definition of a vector space.

Comment: So we can make our own vectors spaces and decide whether any vector f is a part of that.

Comment: @TimCrosby Yes, as long as your own vector space satisfies the axioms of a vector space.

Comment: @TimCrosby Most vector spaces have infinitely many vectors, and maybe even infinitely many dimensions. But there are also vector spaces that contain finitely many vectors, the trivial one being $V=\{0\}$ and the nontrivial ones being finite fields.

Comment: Thanks a bunch !

Comment: @trisct One last doubt. If f and g be a component of a finite vector, then f+g will be also a part of V. Then f +(f+g) will also be part and so on . Then the vector field no longer remains finite except for V=0

Comment: Sorry but there are a few places in your statement that confuse me. (i) $f$ and $g$ aren't components of a vector, they are themselves vectors. (ii) What do you mean by "finite vector", when there's probably no length defined in the space? (iii) I am not sure why you keep saying $f$ is "part of" $V$, as if you think of $f$ as a subset of $V$ (which is incorrect, $f$ is an element of $V$). (iv) No "vector field" is involved here. These imply you may still have some wrong ideas about vector spaces, and I am not sure what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @TimCrosby But don't be discouraged...I've been there. It is not easy to go from Euclidean vectors to vectors in general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110127/discussion-between-tim-crosby-and-trisct).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "solution" involved here.

If you are in the finite  dimensional case $x$, $y\in{\mathbb R}^n$, and you are given two vectors
$$x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n),\quad y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots, y_n)$$
then their *scalar product* $\langle x,y\rangle$ is defined by
$$\langle x,y\rangle:=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\, y_k\ .\tag{1}$$
This scalar product is a real number. When $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ (by coincidence, or careful choosing of $x$ and $y$) then $x$ and $y$ are called *orthogonal*, because if $n=3$ then $x$ and $y$ are then orthogonal in the euclidean sense.

This idea can be transferred to an infinite dimensional setting. Assume, our vector space $V$ consists of all reasonable functions $f:\>[a,b]\to{\mathbb R}$. Such an $f$ can be considered as a "vector with infinitely many components". Note that we can write a vector $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$ as
$$x=(x_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}\ .$$
In the same way we can write an $f\in V$ as
$$f=\bigl(f(x)\bigr)_{a\leq x\leq b}\ .$$
Formula $(1)$ then would lead to
$$\langle f,g\rangle:=\sum_{a\leq x\leq b}f(x)\,g(x)\qquad(????)\ .$$
Such a sum of uncountably many terms of course makes no sense. But we can replace it with an integral over $[a,b]$, where also the $x$ are treated "uniformly". In this way one arrives at the **definition**:
$$\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\>dx\ .$$
This scalar product $\langle f,g\rangle$ is again a real number. And *one calls* $f$ and $g$ *orthogonal* if $\langle f,g\rangle=0$, even when you don't have a threedimensional intuition for this functional orthogonality.

Answer (score 1):

**Intuition**

$a=(a_1,a_2)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)$ are orthogonal if when you multiply element by element and then summarize, you get zero: $a_1b_1+a_2b_2=0$.

A function is an $\infty$-lengthed vector: $f=(f(1),f(2),f(\pi),f(18.4),\ldots)$. To check if $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal you do the same: $\sum\limits_{x\in \mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x) =0$.
Alas, such summation does not really exists (there are two many real numbers...) so the "proper" mathematical way to do it is to integrate $f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: Its great to think that f is $infty$ lengthed vector, all are solutions